# Newbie Modeler Question: How to unbend a character arm before rigging

Tags: modeling

I'm just learning Blender, and have figured out a lot, but I haven't grasped a lot of modeling yet. I have a character (Slimer from Ghostbusters) that I'm trying to rig but it came posed, not in a T pose. I'm not good enough to figure out how to bend his arms back into a T pose without destroying the mesh. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Try to set the 3D cursor at the shoulder, then grab the arm and rotate the arm around the 3D cursor. Proportional editing might help keep things smooth around the shoulder.

Comment: This worked. I forgot about Proportional Editing, and it just took some careful work to get it straightened out. Then I went into Sculpt mode and fixed some of the bulging. Since its a crazy creature it won't look odd to be slightly deformed. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The character may have been modeled that way and in that case there's not much you can do without deforming the mesh in some way to get it to be in a T pose.